# compression condition permutation

Tags: c#, performance, combinatorics

I have 16 permutations each with 104 variables using the standard alphabet. The 104 variable permutation is selected based off of compression complexity.
This is one example of the pattern I am able to generate it has a low compression ratio of 1.3 with overhead:

> HHHFHHFFHHFHHFFHHFHHHFHAAAAHHHFHHFFHHFHHFFHHFHHHFHAAAAHHHFHHFFHHFHHFFHHFHHHFHAAAAHHHFHHFFHHFHHFFHHFHHHFH

This is a goal pattern I would like to generate it has a better compression ratio of 1.5

> mlcllltlgvalvcgvpamdipqtkqdlelpklagtwhsmamatnnislmatlkaplrvhitsllptpednleivlhrwennscvekkvlgektenpkkfkinytvaneatlldtdydnflflclqdtttpiqsmmcqylarvlveddeimqgfirafrplprhlwylldlkqmeepcrf

This is one set of permutation code generation:

```
static double GetCompressionRatio(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    GZipStream gzip2 = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);

    byte[] raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    gzip2.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    gzip2.Close();

    byte[] zipped = ms.ToArray(); // as a BLOB
    int startsize = raw.Length;

    double percent = Convert.ToDouble(zipped.Length) / Convert.ToDouble(startsize);
    return percent;
}

var query = 
             from sp1 in polar
                    ...
                    //22 lines
                    ...
             from vp15 in polar                           
             where GetCompressionRatio(sp1+...+vp15)>1.5      
             select sp1+...+vp15;


foreach (var element in query)
{
    //output
}
        string[] polar = new string[6];
        polar[0]="H";
        polar[1]="Q";
        polar[2]="N";
        polar[3]="K";
        polar[4]="D";
        polar[5]="E";

        string[] nonpolar = new string[5];
        nonpolar[0]="F";
        nonpolar[1]="L";
        nonpolar[2]="I";
        nonpolar[3]="M";
        nonpolar[4]="V";

        string[] all = new string[24];
        all[0]="A";
        all[1]="B";
        all[2]="C";
        all[3]="D";
        all[4]="E";
        all[5]="F";
        all[6]="G";
        all[7]="H";
        all[8]="I";
        all[9]="J";
        all[10]="K";
        all[11]="L";
        all[12]="M";
        all[13]="N";
        all[14]="O";
        all[15]="P";
        all[16]="Q";
        all[17]="R";
        all[18]="S";
        all[19]="T";
        all[20]="U";
        all[21]="V";
        all[22]="W";
        all[23]="Y";
```

I need it to go much faster like 1000x if possible.

Comment: Could you write this up better? I am forced to read the code since I do not understand the description, but the code is not complete either.

Comment: Are you using the badness of compression to evaluate randomness?  If so, there's better ways to evaluate randomness.

Comment: @Corbin yes i am

Comment: i directly called random for each variable in the proper order and it gave sufficiently random and complex results very quickly

Comment: To improve performance this code needs to be more complete, the single method is rather simplistic though doesn't appear to serve a known useful purpose? The performance loss is likely in the iterations you're executing against that method, there may be a way to complete their goal with less iterations if you would show those parts of the code.

Comment: I'd suggest using a dedicated library like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics to generate your permutations. (disclaimer: blatant self promotion... I just deployed this to Nuget yesterday) though I've a feeling your perf. bottle neck is not the generation of the permutations but the actual GetCompressionRatio method.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa which single method are you referring too? the sheer volume of iterations is impossible for a normal computer to process in a reasonable time i believe. i showed all the code that did anything..

Comment: @EoinCampbell the compression does slow the algorthim down some but the sheer volume of data and number of iterations is so many i dont think any library is going to help processes it all atm.

Comment: Edit your question and add your sample data what is the value of polar. Where does the "16 Permutations" come into it. (i only count 15 if you go from sp1 -> vp15). you're first example is 105 characters long. Youre second example is 181 characters long. what are these. where do they come from. Post your entire code if you want it reviewed/improved.

Comment: @EoinCampbell i added the contents of polar nonpolar and all but i dont think a non random sample solution will work i also tried to explain in the code that there are more beptween sp1 and vp15 than you can see but thats not really important

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.

Lots of stuff going on here and I'm writing this as I work your example so bear with me...

In you code, polar contains six letters. And you don't care about letter repetition in your top examples so what you are calculating here are not permutations but variations. Secondly, you're example shows 22 ommitted lines so you have 24 `from` statements in your LINQ query... that's going to generate 6^24 variations (4738381338321616896)

That's a very large number. Even if you could paralelize this across 1000 servers, they would still need to be calculating 150million compressions ratios per second for this to complete in a year. (((6^24)/1000)/365)/86400) = ~150,253,000

As soon as you call `foreach (var element in query)` that query is going to execute and it's going to try and create a list of 4.7 Quintillion strings in memory. This is BAD. You're attempting a brute force calculation on an impossibly large problem set so you need to go back and rethink your approach to whatever it is you are trying to solve/accomplish

But again... lets just assume that you have enough power & bandwidth & compute resource (GPUs are shiny) And lets bring it back to more manageable numbers. lets says 6^10 =

1. Strings in General

Strings are immutable in .NET. Everytime you alter a string, you throw away the old one, and make a new one and the garbage collector has to come along and clean up after you. so this part here will be very expensive where you concat all those strings together, twice.

```
where GetCompressionRatio(sp1+...+vp15)>1.5      
select sp1+...+vp15;
```

at the very least you would want to change this to

```
let concatval = sp1+...+vp15
where GetCompressionRation(concatVal) > 1.5
select concatVal
```

1. Big Numbers are Big.

Using LINQ like that to generate your variations is not optimal. As I suggested in the comments... use a library. The following code snippet.

```
var polar = new[] { "H", "Q", "N", "K", "D", "E" };

var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var results1 = from a1 in polar from a2 in polar
                from a3 in polar from a4 in polar
                from a5 in polar from a6 in polar
                from a7 in polar from a8 in polar
                from a9 in polar from a10 in polar
                select a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 + a9 + a10;
var l1 = results1.Count();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("{0} variations in {1}ms", l1, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var results2 = new Variations<string>(polar, 10, GenerateOption.WithRepetition);
var l2 = results2.Count();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("{0} variations in {1}ms", l2, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.ReadLine();
```

RESULTS

```
60466176 variations in 54161ms
60466176 variations in 4624ms
```

1. The Compression Method.

On my machine this is repeatedly capable of performing 100,000 compressions on a 10 character string in 2200-2300ms. With the following modifications, that comes down to 1800-1900ms. Small improvement that's possibly related to what else my machine was doing but still.

- `MemoryStream` & `GZipStream` are `IDisposable` & should be wrapped in `using()` statements
- removed unnecessary int assignments
- removed unnecessary if(check) at top... you know this to be impossible based on your input set.

Code

```
static float GetCompressionRatio2(string input)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var gzip2 = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
        var raw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        gzip2.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
        var percent = ((float)ms.ToArray().Length) / raw.Length;
        return percent;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw the Variations class comes from this Library.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics

Comment: btw, why `float` and not `double`?